# Insert date and time from Excel sheet into DB with PHP

Tags: php, database, excel, datetime

I have Excel sheet which has different column,but i need  to add some specific column in the data base(email,date and time).The date start from 9/7/14 and every things work well until 9/12/14 ,but when the day become 13 up to end of the month ,I'm getting 1970-01-01 01:00:00 into the data base,again when the month change to 10 ,everything is fine until 10/12/14 and again form 13 I'm getting 1970-01-01 01:00:00 into the data base.

this is my insert.php code

```
session_start();
$target_dir = $_SESSION["targetDir"];
$file_name = $_SESSION["fileName"];

 ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
  require_once 'excel_reader2.php';
  require_once 'dbConn.php';
 $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($target_dir);
 for($i=0;$i<count($data->sheets);$i++) // Loop to get all sheets in a file.
     {
switch ($i) {
    case 1:
         echo "<p class='font_p'>Rows in Sheet $i : " . count($data->sheets[$i]['cells'])."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" ;
        $countWithHeader = count($data->sheets[$i]['cells']);
        $finalCount = $countWithHeader - 1;

        for ($j = 1; $j <= count($data->sheets[$i]['cells']); $j++) // loop used to get each row of the sheet
        {
            $data->sheets[$i]['cells'][$j][1];
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $data->sheets[$i]['cells'][$j][1]);
            $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $data->sheets[$i]['cells'][$j][2]);
            $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $data->sheets[$i]['cells'][$j][3]);
            $in_time = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $data->sheets[$i]['cells'][$j][5]);
            $out_time = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $data->sheets[$i]['cells'][$j][6]);

            $timestampIn = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($in_time));
            $timestampOut = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($out_time));

            $query = "INSERT INTO study_table (email,last_name,first_name,in_time,out_time)
                      VALUES ('".$email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$timestampIn."','".$timestampOut."')";

            mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        }
        break;

    case 2:
```

Comment: Can you show us `var_dump($in_time);` and `var_dump($out_time);` ?

Comment: this is var_dump($in_time);var_dump($out_time); for 9/14/14 when the problem happens: string(16) "14/09/2014 14:50"
string(16) "14/09/2014 15:13"

Comment: strtotime() returns false, because php parses 14/09/2014 as m/d/Y, but you are trying to use it as d/m/Y. Use DateTime::createFromFormat() or str_replace('/', '-', $in_time) before sending it to strtotime()

Comment: Thanks Glavić I will try and let you know if it works.

Comment: sure ,It did .I cant vote up since it require 15 reputation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `strtotime()` will return `false` in your code:

```
$timestampIn = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($in_time));
```

because `$in_time` has invalid format (`14/09/2014 14:50`). Function parses `14/09/2014` as `m/d/Y` format, but you are trying to use it as `d/m/Y`. [See here for demo](https://eval.in/233339).

Easy solution would be to just replace date delimiter `/` to `-`, because then format is changed to `d-m-Y`, which is valid, and `strtotime()` will know how to parse it. [See here for demo](https://eval.in/233340) and please [RTM here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) to see what are valid date formats.

Best solution to parse unknown format it to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method:

```php
$in_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('!d/m/Y H:i', $in_time);
echo $in_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/233341)</kbd>